# How do you create a 3d array which increase the value with each layer in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

i.e, a 3d matrix where all the values on each layer are the same, but the value on each sheet increments as the layers are increased.

The increment could be defined by x = (0:0.5:2*pi), for example.

I've tried using repmat, but this only seems to produce the matrix in another orientation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `repmat` and `permute`:

```
x = (0:0.5:2*pi);
y = repmat(x',[1,5,5]);
z = permute(y,[2,3,1]);
size(z)
ans =

    5    5   13

z(:,:,1)
ans =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0

z(:,:,2)
ans =

   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000
   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000
```

Answer (score 4):

One more possibility: use `ndgrid`, used here to create a 4-by-5-by-#x array:

```
x = 0:0.5:2*pi;

[~,~,out] = ndgrid(1:4,1:5,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define x

```
x = (0:0.5:2*pi);
```

This will have the values varying along the row (2nd dimension). Change your x to vary along the dimension you want (3rd dimension):

```
x = permute(x, [1, 3, 2]);
```

then repmat it:

```
x = repmat(x, [3, 3, 1]);
```